# Incrementing a tabindex property in Ember template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to display forms with a mixin that automatically increments the tabindex property in forms.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  computed,
  Mixin
} = Ember;

export default Mixin.create({

  baseTabIndex: 0,

  tabindex: computed('baseTabIndex', function() {
    this.incrementProperty('baseTabIndex');
    return this.get('baseTabIndex');
  }).volatile()

});
```

In templates, I'd use it like so:

```
{{input value=foo tabindex=tabindex}}
{{input value=bar tabindex=tabindex}}
```

I thought that volatile would mean that the value wasn't cached so I'd get 1, 2 as the values. But it's always 1. How can I do this with a computed property?

Comment: Minor point but you can just do `return this.incrementProperty('baseTabIndex');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for are [class-based helpers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers). You might have trouble with the resetting of the value, so keep an eye open for alternative solutions.